# Checking value in a textbox for inclusion in a database

Tags: database, vb.net, linq, validation, textbox

I'm just setting up a password reset form.  The user will enter their email address in a textbox and then send that to my password reset account.  I am looking for a way to check if the email address they have entered is a valid address contained in my database, `User` table with `User_Number, Email, Name` etc.  Note that the user will not be logged in at this stage.  I am using linq vb.net

Comment: So your question is how to check if the email address exists in the table?

Comment: yes @ajakblackgoat that's basically it.  A user enters an email address into a text box and I want the program to check if the email address exists in my `user` table.  If it does then I will send an email.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to see if the email exists in the DB and nothing else:

```
Dim valid = context.Users.Any(Function(u) u.Email = Textbox.Text);
```

Comment: thanks.  When i put that in, translated to VB, it says that `Any` is not a member of System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal.  All I require is to check that the email the  user is typing in exists in my database.  If it does then I will send an email.

Comment: How do you access your `User` table?  Linq to SQL?  Entity Framework? Datasets?  Basically my answer just assumed that you were using Entity framework (will work with Linq to SQL, too).

Comment: Apologies.  I'm using linq, but I did make sure to open a LinqDataClasseContext in the method.  Does the `Any` function work ok in VB?

Comment: Sure does!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Your data class context should have a `User` property to call the `Any()` function on...

Comment: Ah I don't know what's going on.  It doesn't like it for whatever reason.  Not to worry.  It isn't the most crucial part of my system.  I don't suppose you know anything about Telerik controls haha.  Been stuck on this stuff for two days.  Oh the joys.

Comment: Do you have `Imports System.Data.Linq` and `Imports System.Linq` at the beginning of the page's codebehind?

Comment: When you put @MikeCofoed's code above, it gives error `Any is not a member of System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal`. Why your `Users` derived from `IPrincipal`?